# How to list all files and put number in front of them , using shell

Tags: bash, shell

I want to **count all files** that I have in my directory and put number in front of them, and in a new line, for example :

```
file.txt nextfile.txt example.txt
```

and the output to be :

```
1.file.txt
2.nextfile.txt
3.example.txt
```

and so on.
i am trying something with : `ls -L |`

Comment: Asked previously: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924251/how-to-number-the-ls-output-in-unix

Comment: @Biglava Just FYI, if you're trying to create a menu system to choose a file by number, numbering ls output would be a bad way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this if you have `nl` installed:

```
ls -1 | nl
```

(*Note* with modern shells (ls usually a built-in) the `-1` part is not needed. And this applies to the below solutions too.)

Or with awk:

```
ls -1 | awk '{print NR, $0}'
```

Or with a single awk command:

```
awk '{c=1 ; for (f in ARGV) {print c, f ; c++ } }' *
```

Or with `cat`:

```
cat -n <(ls -1)
```

Comment: Are there any shells besides busybox ash that have `ls` built in?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using shell built-in `printf` in a `for loop`:

```
n=0
for i in *; do
   printf "%d.%s\n" $((n++)) "$i"
done
```